# popup layer inside scrollable div

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

I have a problem that is driving me nuts. I have a gridview inside scrollable div. when I click the gridview header I can see small overlay div (z-index:10) with filtering options.

The problem is that when I move horizontal scrollbar of the parent div the filtering div is moving as well.

How to “nailed” it so it is placed under header column all the time? Should I use some JavaScript to update its position or it can be done with css?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard without seeing the code but generally add position: relative to the parent element and add position:absolute to the child element to have it 'nailed' within its parent element.

of course then use top: -px and left: -px to set a value for its position within the element.

Comment: thank you for quick response. 

Yes it did the trick but there is still another problem.
The nested div can be higher than the parent div if for example grid has only one row. Then only the part of nested div is visible.
thank you for quick response.

Comment: Your questions have a much higher cahnce of been answered if you include your code in a JSFiddle. Google it and try ask the question again with that attached, that way people can see your code and understand your question better